# wordpress image upload for custom post type

Tags: php, wordpress

I'm creating an image upload form for a custom post type but i don't know how to upload the image to the custom post type.  The custom post type is called 'art'.

Here is my code.

form html

```
<form id="art_submission_form" enctype="multipart/form-data" method="post" action="art_process.php">
     <div class="art_upload_container" <?php echo $style; ?>>
            <div class="art_sub_row">
            <select class="art_sub_select" name="art_creation_date">
                <option value="Creation Date">Creation Date</option>
            <?
                $dates = array("2014","2013","2012","2011","2010","2009","2008","2007","2006","2005","2004","2003","2002","2001","2000","1999",
                "1998","1997","1996","1995","1994","1993","1992","1991","1990","1989","1988","1987");

                foreach($dates as $value) {
                    echo "<option value='$value'>$value</option>";
                }
            ?>
            </select>

            <div class="art_sub_col"><label>Art Title</label><input type="text" class="art_title" name="art_title[]" value="<?php echo $art_title; ?>" /></div>
            </div>
            <div class="art_sub_row">
            <div class="art_sub_col"><label>Width(cm)</label><input type="text" class="art_width" name="art_width[]" value="<?php echo $art_width; ?>" /></div>
            <div class="art_sub_col"><label>Height(cm)</label><input type="text" class="art_height" name="art_height[]" value="<?php echo $art_height; ?>" /></div>
            <div class="art_sub_col"><label>Price</label><input type="text" class="art_price" name="art_price[]" value="<?php echo $art_price; ?>" /></div>
            </div>
                <div class="art_sub_row">
            <div class="art_sub_col"><label>Upload Art:</label> <input type="file" name="art_upload[]" class="art_upload"></div>
            </div>
        </div>
<input type="submit" class="art_sub_send" value="Send" />
</form>
```

art_process.php - what i've done so far

```
  $art_title = $_POST['art_title'];

    $i = 0;
    foreach($art_title as $value) {
    $art_title = $_POST['art_title'][$i];
    $art_width = $_POST['art_width'][$i];
    $art_height = $_POST['art_height'][$i];
    $art_price = $_POST['art_price'][$i];
    $art_creation_date = $_POST['art_creation_date'][$i];


  // Add the content of the form to $post as an array
    $new_post = array(
        'post_title'    => $art_title,
        'post_status'   => 'draft',    
        'post_type' => 'art'
    );
    //save the new post
    $pid = wp_insert_post($new_post); 


    $i++;
    }
```

Is there a built in wordpress function to upload image to a custom post type?

Answer (score 0):

[`media_handle_upload()`](http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/media_handle_upload) is the function you're looking for:

> handles the file upload POST request, and creates the attachment post
>   in the database.

If successful, you can use the parent post ID (`$pid`) and the attachment ID to set the image as post thumbnail with [`set_post_thumbnail()`](http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/set_post_thumbnail).

Comment: could i have an example on how to implement with my code?

Comment: does media_handle_upload function handle validation also?

Comment: If validation means limit to images, `media_sideload_image()` might be a better option for you: http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/media_sideload_image Some useful info here: http://wordpress.stackexchange.com/q/141172